# it is possible to convert subselect with max function into SAS datastep?

Tags: sas, aggregate, proc, datastep, subquery

it is possible to convert code below from proc sql into sas datastep?

```
proc sql;
create table CAL_CHECK as
select t1.DT_REP 
     , t1.BANK_FLAG
     , (select MAX(t2.DT_REP) as LAST_BD_BANK_FLAG from CZ_LOOK.CZ_CALENDAR t2 where t2.DT_REP < t1.DT_REP and t2.BANK_FLAG='Y') as LAST_BD 
from CZ_LOOK.CZ_CALENDAR t1
where dt_rep between &first_day. and &last_day.;
quit;
```

thanks for response

example:

```
DT_REP      LAST_BD
01.04.2020  31.03.2020
02.04.2020  01.04.2020
03.04.2020  02.04.2020
04.04.2020  03.04.2020
05.04.2020  03.04.2020
06.04.2020  03.04.2020
07.04.2020  06.04.2020
08.04.2020  07.04.2020
```

1.4. was Wednesday, so last banking day is 31.3, 
5.4. was Sunday, so the last banking day is 3.4, 
6.4. was Monday, so the last banking day is 3.4. to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The sub-select is a self correlated sub-selected.

One might consider LAG as suitable, however, the bank_flag conditional makes it impossible to use LAG for the task at hand.

Retaining `last_bd` and updating its value only *after* using its value from prior state will in essence lag the variable conditionally as needed.

Example:

```
data CZ_CALENDAR;
  input (DT_REP LAST_BD) (ddmmyy10.:) bank_flag: $1. ;
  format dt_rep last_bd yymmdd10.;
datalines;
31.03.2020  .           Y Tue
01.04.2020  31.03.2020  Y Wed
02.04.2020  01.04.2020  Y Thu
03.04.2020  02.04.2020  Y Fri
04.04.2020  03.04.2020  N Sat
05.04.2020  03.04.2020  N Sun
06.04.2020  03.04.2020  Y Mon
07.04.2020  06.04.2020  Y Tue
08.04.2020  07.04.2020  Y Wed
;

%let first_day = '01JAN2020'D;
%let last_day = "&SYSDATE."D;

%put NOTE: &=first_day;
%put NOTE: &=last_day;

proc sql;
  create table CAL_CHECK as
  select
    t1.DT_REP 
    , t1.BANK_FLAG
    , ( select MAX(t2.DT_REP) as LAST_BD_BANK_FLAG 
       from CZ_CALENDAR t2 
       where t2.DT_REP < t1.DT_REP and t2.BANK_FLAG='Y'
      )
      as LAST_BD 
  from
    CZ_CALENDAR t1
  where
    dt_rep between &first_day. and &last_day.;
quit;

proc print data=CAL_CHECK;
  title "SQL";
  format dt_rep last_bd WEEKDATE.;
run;

proc sort data=cz_calendar;
  by dt_rep;

data cal_check2(where=(dt_rep between &first_day. and &last_day.));
  set cz_calendar;

  OUTPUT;

  * save dt_rep from most recent bank_flag day;
  retain last_bd;
  if bank_flag = 'Y' then last_bd = dt_rep;
run;

proc print data=CAL_CHECK2;
  title "DATA step";
  format dt_rep last_bd WEEKDATE.;
run;
```

Output
[image]

Comment: thanks for respons, but this does not work well because in column LAST_BD is the same  date as in DT_REP, but colum LAST_BD should contain different date -- last banking day

an example was added to the first post

Comment: There was a typo.  Should be `if bank_flag = 'Y' then last_bd = prior_dt_rep;`. Answer fixed.

Comment: it  will not work correctly... you can not use lag function, because after the weekend (Monday) the previous banking day is not Sunday, but Friday. Look at the example.

And the code above does not return values for weekend days

Comment: Thanks for the sample data.  Code in answered edited to produce same as SQL.  Assignment for tracking the most recent bank day in a retained variable occurs after explicit `output`, and output data set option `where=` used to restrict range.  Can't use where **statement** in data step because the first 'last_bd' would not be computable.